# How can I disable receiving notification in a specific activity in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Chat app, but I receive notification while I am in the chat activity.
I want to disable it and just get notification when I am not in the chat activity.

Answer (score 1):

While you could somehow flag the app instance to not receive messages from FCM while it's showing a specific activity, that would be likely be quite unreliable as there are many factors affecting delivering.

The better approach would be to receive the message, but ignore it while the activity is showing, either in your [`onMessageReceived` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived) or in code further downstream that handles it. Since notifications are only displayed by the system when your app is **not** active, ignoring the messages while the app is active will have the same effect as not receiving them, and is more reliable.